# What is the purpose of claims request parameter on OAuth 2.0?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

OpenID specification 5.5 explain RP can request claims using claims request parameter. http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClaimsParameter

What is the purpose of this feature?

Is it this feature create security vulnerabilities as user able to set claims?

For example user can modify URL on browser into:

```
https://op.example.com/authorize?
response_type=code
&client_id=client
&redirect_uri=https://client.example.com
&scope=openid
&claims={“userinfo” : {“sub”: { “value” : “superuser”}} , “id_token” : {“sub”: { “value” : “superuser” }}}
```

If OP implements this feature, then OP put that claims into id token and user info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of this feature is to request claims, possibly with a certain desired value. It does not mean that the RP is able to set claim values. Instead the OP should verify which of the requested claims and values match for the authenticated user and return only those claims that are valid.

Comment: which means , for example in db i saved the sub with x and y. the claim contains y , i should give access token only if the user y logged in ? if not I should error ? or ?